# How to sample for each id on Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, sample

I have a dataset with **1000 distinct id**, lets call them *id_ref*.

On the same dataset, i have a lot of other id (lets call them *id_to_sample*). The id_to_sample can be associeted to multiple id_ref.

I want for **each id_ref, 4 other id_to_sample** .
Moreover, i want id_to_sample to **be selected uniquly and randomly.**

In conclusion, we will have a dataset with **4000 rows**, with  **1000 distinct id_ref  and 4000 distinct id_to_sample.**

So far i have tired this method:

```
sel distinct id_ref, id_to_sample  
qualify row_number() over (partition by id_ref order by randommm )<= 4
from
(sel *, random(1,10000) as randommm
from dataset)t ;
```

Any idea?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe approach it in reverse. First, for each unique id_to_sample, choose only one id_ref. Then from that result, for each id_ref choose your 4 id_to_sample.